# Mixing sed backreferences with bash variables

Tags: bash, sed, escaping

I am running an old version of git and I am writing a script that updates the host name configuration.

My problem is that I can't figure out the right escape character combinations so that a variable is not mixed with the back-reference used in my regex.

Here is my best effort

```
#!/bin/bash
#code
foo=`ec2-describe-instances i-f95e4b82 | grep amazon | awk '{print $4}'`
sed -i "s/\(ec2-user@\)\(.*\)\(:repo\.git\)/\\1 $foo \\3/" /var/www/.git/config
```

This puts a space between the first back-reference and the variable foo. The hope is to not have that space between the first back reference and $foo. I suspect I could use a literal instead of the backreference, but the user names and repos may change.

Any ideas?

**Edit**

```
"s/\(ec2-user@\)\(.*\)\(:repo\.git\)/\\1$foo\\3/"
```

Does not produce the right answer because foo is amalgamated with the 1, producing the wrong back reference. I can't figure out how to escape $foo.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is what you think it is? Because `sed` should have no problems with a back-reference immediately followed by other text, even including numbers. For example, `echo abc | sed 's/\(a\)/\12/'` prints `a2bc`. This is because, per the POSIX specification, `sed` only supports up to nine sub-expressions, referred to as `\1` through `\9`.

Comment: "s/\(ec2-user@\)\(.*\)\(:repo\.git\)/\\1$foo\\3/" does not produce the right answer

Comment: So, what does it produce instead? And what does `sed --version` print?

Comment: For the record, the antipattern `grep x | awk '{stuff}'` can usually be refactored to just `awk '/x/{stuff}'`

Comment: Use single quotes for sed commands i.e. `'s/\(ec2-user@\)\(.*\)\(:repo\.git\)/\1'"$foo"'\3/'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to isolate the `$foo` variable so  you don't need spaces around it to distingusih its name from the other surrounding characters. Try

```
sed -i "s/\(ec2-user@\)\(.*\)\(:repo\.git\)/\\1${foo}\\3/" /var/www/.git/config
```

If you want only a space after foo, then use

```
sed -i "s/\(ec2-user@\)\(.*\)\(:repo\.git\)/\\1${foo} \\3/" /var/www/.git/config
```

IHTH